# jQuery if readonly = true only clear part of form

Tags: forms, readonly, jquery

I have 2 jQuery snippets 1st is toggle readonly and the 2nd is a submit form.

**Toggle readonly:**

```
$('#lock').toggle( function () {
    $('#handle').attr('readonly', true).addClass('disabled');
return false;
 } , function() {
  $('#handle').attr('readonly', false).removeClass('disabled');
return false;
});
```

**Submit form:**

```
$('button').click(function() {
var handle     = $('#handle').val();
var msg        = $('#msg').val();
var dataString = 'handle='+ handle + '&msg=' + msg;

if(handle=='' || msg=='') {
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
} else {

$.ajax({
  type    : 'POST',
  url     : 'form.php',
  data    : dataString,
  success : function(){
$('#foo').load('page.php');
}}
 });
}
 return false;
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is

*if readonly = true do not reset "handle" value*

otherwise reset both, so I need to get the status of the 1st snippet (toggle readonly) and allow the 2nd (form) to distinguish whether its  true or false.

I tried this in success: but it didn't work.

```
if($('#handle').attr('readonly', true)){
    $('#msg').val('');
    }else{
    $('#handle, #msg').val('');
```

Comment: Inspect output of the `$('#handle').attr('readonly', true)`. Realize what the issue is. Fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
if ($('#handle').is('[readonly]')) {
    $('#msg').val('');
}
else {
    $('#handle, #msg').val('');
}
```

Also for use

```
​$('#handle').prop('readonly', true)
```

instead of

```
$('#handle').attr('readonly', true)
```